Why aren't any of the mouseEvent() working for me?
I am trying to make this phrase switch each time a mouse event occurs. I don't really care which mouse event, I tried mouseover and others because I thought that would be cool. I am getting something wrong, but I have no idea what is wrong. I already have the  tag.


const hello = document.getElementById("hello");
const ciao = document.getElementById("ciao");
const hola = document.getElementById("hola");
const bonjour = document.getElementById("bonjour");


function disappear(variable) {
  variable.style.display = 'none';
};

function appear(variable) {
  variable.style.display = 'block';
};

hello.addEventListener('click', disappear(hello));
ciao.addEventListener('click', appear(ciao));

ciao.addEventListener('click', disappear(ciao));
hola.addEventListener('click', appear(hola));

hola.addEventListener('click', disappear(hola));
bonjour.addEventListener('click', appear(bonjour));

bonjour.addEventListener('click', disappear(bonjour));
hello.addEventListener('click', appear(hello));
<div class="hello-world">
  <button id="hello"> Hello, World! </button>
  <button id="ciao"> Ciao, Mondo!</button>
  <button id="hola"> Hola, Mundo!</button>
  <button id="bonjour"> Bonjour le monde!</button>
</div>




It works, once you click hello, it will run hello.addEventListener('click', disappear(hello)); and become display: none, then run hello.addEventListener('click', appear(hello)); and become display: block again.

If you use parenthesis after a function name, you are calling the function immediately. What you need to do is pass the reference to that function , not calling it.

you have a major flaw in your idea. If you make an element disappear, it will be visually gone. You can not click on it or trigger any other "mouse event" on that element as it is gone. As such you can not make it re-appear! You probably want to hide the element with visibility: hidden

The answer from "het" is correct. You need to pass a function, not call it. However, you can also fix your code by having your appear/disappear functions return a callback, so there's a bit more reusability:
function disappear(variable) {
   return () => variable.style.display = 'none';
}
function appear(variable) {
   return () => variable.style.display = 'block';
}


You are trying to add undefined as a click listener, returned from appear/disappear function.
You should pass a function instead.
hello.addEventListener('click', () => {
  disappear(hello);
});


hi thanks so much for responding, can you elaborate. I was thinking the event handler function would be the disappear/ appear & I wouldn’t have to put another function.
